# Am I reading Introduction to Loring W Tu order correctly?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question

This is a simple question I am currently reading Loring W Tu. I feel like the chapter of Lie groups can be skipped at the end. More precisely, I want to read chapter 5 on differential forms, chapter 6 on integration, and chapter 7 on De-Rham cohomology before going back towards chapter 4. Is reading this way messing with my understanding or is it ok ?

Comment: You can skip that chapter for the path that you want to pursue.

Comment: Ok. Great thanks!

Comment: I don't know the book. Plausibly he might talk about the action of a Lie group and differential forms invariant under that action and how they relate to the DeRham cohomology.